# Typed racket GUI: pasteboard method set-area-selectable not working

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I using the typed/racket/gui package to build an application. I need to turn off the selection box of the pasteboard% that is activated by default. Usually you would do this using the method [set-area-selectable](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/pasteboard_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._pasteboard%7E25%29._set-area-selectable%29%29) but somehow it is not working for me as I am getting this error:

```
  Type Checker: send: method not understood by object
  method name: set-area-selectable
  object type: (Instance Pasteboard%)
  in: (send this set-area-selectable #f)
  location...:
```

Here is my code:

```
(define-type Graph-Pasteboard%
    (Class #:implements/inits Pasteboard%)
)
(: graph-pasteboard% : Graph-Pasteboard%)
(define graph-pasteboard%
    (class pasteboard%
    (super-new)
    (: do-paste (Integer -> Void))
    (define/override (do-paste time) (void))

    (send this set-area-selectable #f)
    ))
```

I have checked the version of that package I have installed and it should support this functionality.

One solution to this would be to override the method [on-default-event](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/pasteboard_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._pasteboard%7E25%29._on-default-event%29%29) but this would mean a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: It looks like the method `set-area-selectable` is just missing from the `Pasteboard%` type. The `Pasteboard%` type is defined here: https://github.com/racket/typed-racket/blob/8b8537328f324ade77bc26be02892f6a7daafce3/typed-racket-more/typed/racket/private/gui-types.rkt#L2486 and I don't see the `set-area-selectable` method in that type, so that's incomplete

Comment: So how would I add it myself?

Comment: I've noticed they resolve things like that pretty quickly if you make an issue or pull request on their Github repo. I had noticed something earlier that was missing and they resolved it in like 2-3 days.

Comment: I have created a new issue on Github and it has been solved by adding the missing part:  https://github.com/racket/typed-racket/issues/978. However I still have the same error even after trying to update the package with raco where it said that  there where no updates.

Comment: It was only merged after branch day... which means it didn't make it into this latest release, but it'll be in the next one

Comment: You can probably get a pre-release snapshot version with it though: https://snapshot.racket-lang.org/

Comment: I have made the changes on my local machine since I am the only one who is currently working on / using this project. The project probably won´t be finished until next release so this should work.